# 3-fold simple branched cover

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Where can I find a proof of the fact that every surface (with one boundary component) is 3-fold simple branched cover of the 2-sphere (2-disc)? I have seen this result in different places but without any reference to a proof.